# Python3 Nmap-APİ

Tags: python, nmap

Nmap API is written in Python and `-v, -o, -A, --script, -Pn` will run these parameters and ask for IP addresses from the user and will transfer the outputs to the "**targets.txt**" file with the `-IL` parameter. can you write the code?

I used nmap3 but I could not run the codes with their parameters.

Comment: Yes, I can write the code. </sarcasm> Now, please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. To make it explicit: SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to install the python-nmap library if you haven't already by running:

```
pip install python-nmap
```

Now, you can use the following Python code:

```
 import nmap

def run_nmap_scan(ip_address):
    # Create an Nmap PortScanner object
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()

    # Define Nmap scan parameters
    scan_arguments = "-v -oN - -A --script=default -Pn"

    # Perform the Nmap scan
    nm.scan(ip_address, arguments=scan_arguments)

    # Get the scan results
    scan_results = nm.csv()

    # Save the scan results to "targets.txt"
    with open("targets.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(scan_results)

    print(f"Scan results saved to targets.txt for {ip_address}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Prompt the user for an IP address
    target_ip = input("Enter the target IP address: ")

    # Run the Nmap scan with the specified parameters
    run_nmap_scan(target_ip)
```

This code defines a function run_nmap_scan that takes an IP address as an argument, runs an Nmap scan with the specified parameters, and saves the results to "targets.txt." The **main** block prompts the user for an IP address and then calls the run_nmap_scan function with the provided IP address.

Note: Adjust the scan_arguments variable to include the parameters you need for your specific use case. The provided example includes some common parameters such as -v, -oN, -A, --script, and -Pn.